# Как в dle 11 расширить вывод {date} в формате: 1 минуту назад?

Tags: php, dle

Всем привет, помогите с датой добавления новостей и комментариев для dle. Весь интернет перерыл не нашел подобного а если и есть, то для профи) голые коды без мануала!

**Пожелание по вопросу:**

Без модулей! просто расширить стандартное dle 11.1 время.

**Время сайта и сервера:** Москва

**Код вывода в шаблоне:** {date=time}

**Формат выводы:**

- 34 секунды назад (в место секунд (только что))
- 1 минуту назад / 12 минут() назад
- 1 час назад
- 1 день назад / 2 дн(я) назад / 18 дн(ей) назад
- 1 месяц назад
- 1 год назад

Если можно пошаговый мануал установки, в php очень слабо разбираюсь!)